# How many of these samples of $5$ students contain at least $1$ woman?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to figure out two separate questions about a sample of 25 students, of whom 10 are women and the rest are men. We take a sample of $5$ students from this class. I know there is a total of $53130$ choices by $\binom{25}{5}$.

How many of these samples of $5$ students contain at least $1$ woman?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, and in questions where you are asked to find how many combinations contain "at least" something, it's often easier to find the complement of the set you are looking for. In this case, you can calculate how many sets of $5$ will contain NO women. When you've found the number of possible groups that exist containing no women, subtract that number from the total you've calculated to find the total number of groups containing at least $1$ woman.

As you calculated, $C(25,5) = 53130$. Since there are 15 men in the group, we can calculate the number of groups in which there are only men by $C(15,5) = 3003$. Now we find the number of groups in which there is at least $1$ woman by subtracting the number of groups in which there are only men from the total number of groups: $C(25,5) - C(15,5) = 53130 - 3003 = 50127$.

So there are $50127$ groups containing at least $1$ woman.

Comment: Formatting is not OK but you can learn from the help site

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

if it contains no woman then you have $\binom {15}{5}$ thus answer is $\binom {25}{5}-\binom {15}{5}= 53130-\binom {15}{5}$